# How clear focus for BasicTextField in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-textfield

I have a Jetpack Compose (Beta04) BasicTextField (with decorationBox). How can I clear the focus?

I have tried with focusRequester but this doesn't works:

```
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }

// ...

BasicTextField(modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester), /* ... */)

// ...

placesFocusRequester.freeFocus()
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

To clear focus from the currently focused component you can use the [`FocusManager.clearFocus`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/focus/FocusManager#clearfocus) method:

```
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    var value by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("initial value") }
    BasicTextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = { value = it },
        decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
            Row(
                Modifier
                    .background(Color.LightGray, RoundedCornerShape(percent = 30))
                    .padding(16.dp)
                    .focusRequester(focusRequester)
            ) {
                //...
                innerTextField()
            }
        }
    )
  
    Button(onClick = { focusManager.clearFocus() }) {
        Text("Clear focus")
    }
```

Comment: How do I achieve the same if I want to clear the focus upon native backpress?

Comment: @AvinashParasurampuram use BackHandler(true){ focusManager.clearFocus() }

Comment: This was surprisingly simple, thanks. For anyone using view models, I'd recommend you keep the FocusRequester in there so you can reuse it elsewhere and set up LocalFocusManager in the composable.

Comment: @AvinashParasurampuram and how can you exit the screen when you override the back action with the `BackHandler` set to always true? That works for removing the focus, but not for you will be stuck on the screen

Comment: what does `focusRequester ` do here?

Answer (score -3):

```
@Composable 
fun InputEditText(
    value: String,
    modifier: Modifier,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    textStyle: TextStyle, hintTextStyle: 
    TextStyle, placeHolderString: String = "",
    enabled: Boolean = true, readOnly: Boolean = false,
    singleLine: Boolean = false,
    maxLines: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
    keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default,
    keyboardActions: KeyboardActions = KeyboardActions.Default,
    cursorColor: Color = Color.Black,
    imageVector: ImageVector,
    iconTint: Color = Color.Gray,
    backColor: Color = Color.White,
    borderColor: Color = Color.LightGray,
    showPassword: Boolean = false,
    backGroundShape: Shape = RectangleShape,
    passwordVisible: MutableState,
    error: String,
    howError: Boolean = false 
) { 
    BasicTextField( 
        visualTransformation = if (showPassword) { 
            if (!passwordVisible.value) VisualTransformation.None else PasswordVisualTransformation() 
        } else { VisualTransformation.None }, 
        value = value, 
        onValueChange = onValueChange, 
        modifier = modifier, 
        textStyle = textStyle, 
        decorationBox = { innerTextField -> 
            Column { 
                Row( 
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(backColor, backGroundShape)
                        .border( width = 1.dp, color = if (showError) Color.Red else borderColor, backGroundShape ) 
                        .padding(14.dp) 
                        .fillMaxWidth(), 
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start, 
                    verticalAlignment = CenterVertically 
                ) { 
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = imageVector, 
                        contentDescription = null, 
                        tint = iconTint, 
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 6.dp) 
                    ) 
                    if (value.isEmpty()) { 
                        Text(
                            text = placeHolderString, 
                            color = hintTextStyle.color, 
                            fontSize = hintTextStyle.fontSize, 
                            fontStyle = hintTextStyle.fontStyle, 
                            fontFamily = hintTextStyle.fontFamily, 
                            textAlign = hintTextStyle.textAlign, 
                            fontWeight = hintTextStyle.fontWeight, 
                            style = hintTextStyle 
                        ) 
                    } 
                    innerTextField() 
                    if (showPassword) { 
                        Column(
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), 
                            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom, 
                            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End 
                        ) { 
                            Image( 
                                painter = painterResource(
                                    id = if (!passwordVisible.value) 
                                        R.drawable.ic_baseline_visibility_off_24 
                                    else R.drawable.ic_baseline_visibility_24
                                ), 
                                contentDescription = "Cart button icon", 
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .size(24.dp)
                                    .clickable { 
                                        passwordVisible.value = !passwordVisible.value 
                                    }, 
                                colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(color = iconTint) 
                            ) 
                        } 
                    } 
                    if (showError) { 
                        Column(
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), 
                            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom, 
                            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End 
                        ) { 
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = Icons.Filled.Info, 
                                contentDescription = null, 
                                tint = Color.Red, 
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 6.dp) 
                            ) 
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
                if (showError) { 
                    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) { 
                        Text(
                            text = error, 
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), 
                            style = TextStyle(
                                color = Color.Red, 
                                fontFamily = FontFamily.SansSerif, 
                                fontSize = 11.sp, 
                                textAlign = TextAlign.Start, 
                            ) 
                        ) 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        }, 
        enabled = enabled,
        readOnly = readOnly, 
        singleLine = singleLine, 
        maxLines = maxLines, 
        keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions, 
        keyboardActions = keyboardActions, 
        cursorBrush = SolidColor(cursorColor) 
    ) 
}
```

Comment: Please add the code in coding format with some explanation to what this code does.